# Regex: Add particular words from list to every 5 words - random

Tags: notepad++, regex, sublime-text-3

I have this words list: `of, in the, that, as to, can, may, due to the fact that`

Also, I have this text/paragraph:

`The teaching methods represent the ways used in the school by the teacher to support the students to discover life, nature, the world, things, science. They are also means by which students' skills, abilities and capacities to act on nature are formed and developed, to use the fruits of knowledge transforming the exterior into interior facilities, forming their character and developing their personality.`

I want to insert the words from list, to every 5 words on the text, without taking into account the .[dots] It doesn't matter if the sentence sounds nice or not, of if has a logic or not. Words list can be insert random, or in the chosen order.

**OUTPUT:**

The teaching methods represent the **OF** ways used in the school **IN THE** by the teacher to support **THAT** the students to discover life, **AS TO** nature, the world, things, science. **CAN** They are also means by **MAY** which students' skills, abilities and **due to the fact that** capacities to act on nature **OF** are formed and developed, to **MAY** use the fruits of knowledge transforming **AS TO** the exterior into interior facilities, **IN THE** forming their character and developing their personality.

FIND: `(?:\S+\s+){5}\S+\K`

REPLACE BY:  `\1may \2if the \3that \4as to`

I believe the replacement is not good. Can anyone help me?

Comment: regex doesn't do random picks

Comment: You can't do such job with regex. You have to write a script in your favorite scripting language.

Answer (score 0):

try this: **((\w+)[\h+:-]){5}** use this expression 5 times, for 5 words

FIND: `(\w+)[\h+:-](\w+)[\h+:-](\w+)[\h+:-](\w+)[\h+:-](\w+)[\h+:-](\w+)[\h+:-](\w+)`

REPLACE BY: `\1 can \2 may \3 that \4 as to \5 of`

OR  you can try with thise formula **\w+(?:-\w+)+**   (5 times)